# Thread safe global variable in an ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement a multi-threaded global variable in my ASP.Net MVC application.

A `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` would be ideal but how do I make this accessible to every user session in my application?

Would something like this do the trick?

```
public static class GlobalStore
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> GlobalVar { get; set; }
}
```

I need multiple users to be able to read and write to/from this object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use HttpContext.current.Application for that like following

To create object

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["GlobalVar"] = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

To get or use object

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> GlobalVar = HttpContext.Current.Application["GlobalVar"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>;
```

**EDIT:**

Edit your static class with static variable not property like following

```
public static class GlobalStore
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> GlobalVar;
}
```

Now set that variable with new object in you global.aspx Application_Start event like following

```
GlobalStore.GlobalVar = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

Then you can use it in your application by

```
    GlobalStore.GlobalVar["KeyWord"] = new DateTime();
DateTime obj = GlobalStore.GlobalVar["KeyWord"] as DateTime;
```

And yes ConcurrentDictionary as well as static variables are thread safe in .net applications

Comment: You have to use Lock() , UnLoak() Method when you try to add update operation on Application. It is not thread safe as far as I know.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.lock(v=vs.110).aspx check out this link for Lock() UnLock()

Comment: I *think* by using the ConcurrentDictionary<T> object that you should not need to lock/unlock perhaps?

Comment: The static variables you set like this will be shared by all the users. Microsoft says that static variables are thread safe, but the main purpose of static variables is that they are shared among all the users. So they are not thread safe in the way user is asking